# replace html content - keep an element

Tags: jquery, ajax

If I have this code:

```
<div class="lists">
     <a href="#new_list">New list</a>
</div>
```

AND

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'xxx.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
         id_user:<?php echo $id;?>
     },
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function (data) {
         $(".lists").html(data); //here
     }
 });
```

It is possible ignore the `.lists>a` when replace the content? What i mean is: add the new content `data` but also keep the original `.lists>a`

thanks

Comment: if data is valid html, you could use `.append(data)` or `.prepend(data)`, search in the documentation for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a backup of `a` inside `lists` and `append/prepend` them later,

```
var $a = $(".lists a").clone();
$(".lists").html(data).append($a);
```

Use `.prepend` insted of `.append` if you want the links to be above the data html

**Note:**

1. Assuming that the `a` tags are always in the top/bottom of the `.lists`.
2. You have lot of other elements inside .lists which you want to replace with data

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're asking for?

Just append the html() and then the data.

Cheers.

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'xxx.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
         id_user:<?php echo $id;?>
     },
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function (data) {
         $(".lists").html( $(".lists").html() + data); //here
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $(".lists a").html(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append()` instead.  Take a gander at the jQuery [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) documentation.